# Logged in Sudo User keeps getting Permission Denied Messages

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, sudo, php

I have been trying to install a LAMP setup on a linux PC under Ubuntu 20.04lts.

I am the primary sudo user and I keep getting "permission denied" messages when trying to save nano files and making directories in the /var/www/html folder.

All the folders in the Computer location of Files have Permissions Greyed out. I guess this means I cannot add to or modify content in those files.

I have installed Apache2, MariahDB and PHP and cannot create or modify any INI files.

Sometimes I get the message that I don't have access because I am not the root user. I thought as the primary Sudo User with seemingly all admin privileges I should would be the actual Root User and have all access privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Just being a "primary sudo user" doesn't empower you at all times. You must preface the commands you wish to execute as `root` with `sudo`

Comment: Obligatory xkcd link: https://xkcd.com/149/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a series of commands as the `root` user without having to prefix every command with `sudo` every time, I recommend using `sudo -i` to grab a login shell as the `root` user. From the manual:

```
-i, --login
                 Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login
                 shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile,
                 .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified,
                 it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no
                 command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change
                 to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The command is run with
                 an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  Note that
                 most shells behave differently when a command is specified as compared to an
                 interactive session; consult the shell's manual for details.  The Command
                 environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects
                 the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
```

Alternatively, if you remember setting a root password during setup (which is unlikely in the case of Ubuntu Server -- the `root` account is normally disabled), you can change user to `root` using the `su root` command.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.